# Error: Missing } inserted after using package {tocloft}

Tags: errors, compiling, tocloft

The compiling was fine before I added \usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}. But Once I used it, the error showed as:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                  }
1.60     \tableofcontents
```

Same thing happened to "\listoffigures" or "\listoftables" if they are uncommented. Anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks.

------------------- My Tex File --------------------

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{arial}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace} 


\begin{document}

   \input{TitlePage.tex}
   \newpage

   \input{Copyright.tex}
   \newpage

   \frontmatter

   \pagestyle{prelim}

   % Redefine plain page style so that the first pages of chapters
   % have desired page style.
   %
   \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
      \fancyhf{}
      \cfoot{-\thepage-}
   }%

   \input{Signature_Page.tex}
   \newpage

   \input{Dedication.tex}
   \newpage

   % Begin Double Spacing
   %
   \singlespacing
   %\doublespacing

   \tableofcontents

   \newpage
   %\listoffigures
   %\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{3.5em}
   \newpage
   %\listoftables
   \newpage
```

Comment: Welcome! Please post a complete, small example document rather than a fragment. That is, if that is really your document, then you should get errors much sooner because you have no `\documentclass`, no `\end{document}` etc. In this case, remove the line loading `subfigure`. It is obsolete and ought not be used.

Comment: Instead of using the deprecated `subfigure` package, do consider using either the [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package or the [subfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package. Either way, as @cfr recommends, do also omit the `subfigure` option when loading `tocloft`.

Comment: That said, the addition of `tocloft` with `subfigure` does not cause errors when I complete your example. I do get errors due to the attempt to load `arial` and use the `prelim` pagestyle.

Comment: I tried to remove 'subfigure', but it still did not work. The ultimate goal is to change the space between bullet # and figure caption in the list of figure. I need to use 'subfigure' or its alternatives in my tex. Also, 'subfig' did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

@BigL, as you've mentioned in your comment above -

> The ultimate goal is to change the space between bullet # and figure caption in the list of figure.

If that's all you are/were looking for, then the following solution should work nicely. My solution is based on the `subcaption package` rather than the now deprecated `subfigure package` you've used in your example *(I can't really call it the `MWE`, as it includes a lot of unnecessary stuff)*.

The `MWE` provided below is pretty much self-explanatory and includes sufficient hints inline. I do realise that it's been a year since this question was posted, however, a brief search for similar problems suggested that I should post an answer here, at least for the sake of posterity.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}         %% to get demo figures
\usepackage{showframe}              %% Shows the actual page layout
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}  %% alternative for subfigure
                                    %% To get subfloats listed in list of figures, you
                                    %% must load the subcaption package with [list=true]
                                    %% option!
%%\usepackage{subfigure}            %% deprecated package!
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}     %% OP's definition
                                    %% subfgure This option is required if, and only if,
                                    %% the tocloft and subfgure packages are being used
                                    %% together. The two packages can be specifed in any
                                    %% order. - From the tocloft package documentation
                                    %% (dated 2013/05/02)

\newcounter{lofdepth}               %% Declare new LoF depth counter
\newcounter{lotdepth}               %% Declare new LoT depth counter
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}            %% Set new LoF depth counter to include subfigures
%%\setcounter{lofdepth}{1}          %% If subfigures are't needed in LoF

%% Adding horizontal space between LoF numbers and entry text
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{1in}                         %% Exaggerated width!
\renewcommand{\cftsubfignumwidth}{1in}                      %% Exaggerated width!

%% Indentation for LoF entry numbers
\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\cftsubfigindent}{2.25em}

%% Vertical skips for LoF entries
\renewcommand{\cftbeforefigskip}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubfigskip}{8pt}

%% Customisation of subfig numbers in the LoF entries
\renewcommand{\cftsubfigpresnum}{[\hspace*{0.5mm}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubfigaftersnum}{{}.\hspace*{0.5mm}]}

%% Figure LoF entries in bold
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftfigdotsep}}

%% To switch-off page numbers of subfigure LoF entries
\cftpagenumbersoff{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
   \cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
   \cleardoublepage
\listoftables
   \cleardoublepage

\chapter{CHAPTER 1}

   \begin{figure}[!ht]
   \vspace*{-20pt}
      \centering
         \begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{}
            \centering
            \caption{First SUB-FLOAT}
            %\label{fig:demo1}
         \end{subfigure}
         \begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{}
            \centering
            \caption{Second SUB-FLOAT}
            %\label{fig:demo2}
         \end{subfigure}
         \begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{}
            \centering  
            \caption{Third SUB-FLOAT}
            %\label{fig:demo3}
         \end{subfigure}
   \caption{Demo Figure 1}
   \end{figure}

\cleardoublepage    

    \section{Section 1}

        \begin{table}[h]    
          \begin{center}
            \vspace*{1.5in}
              \scalebox{1.25}{  
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                  \hline
                   Mineral & Color \\
                  \hline
                  \hline                                    
                  Ruby & red \\
                  \hline
                  \hline                            
                  Sapphire & blue \\
                  \hline
                \end{tabular}   
              }         
          \end{center}
            \caption{Demo Table 1}
            \vspace*{50pt}
        \end{table}                 

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\cleardoublepage        

\chapter{CHAPTER 2}

   \begin{figure}[!ht]
   \vspace*{-20pt}
      \centering
         \begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{}
            \centering
            \caption{First SUB-FLOAT}
            %\label{fig:demo1}
         \end{subfigure}
         \begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{}
            \centering
            \caption{Second SUB-FLOAT}
            %\label{fig:demo2}
         \end{subfigure}
         \begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{}
            \centering  
            \caption{Third SUB-FLOAT}
            %\label{fig:demo3}
         \end{subfigure}
   \caption{Demo Figure 2}
   \end{figure}

\cleardoublepage

\cleardoublepage    

    \section{Section 2}

        \begin{table}[h]    
          \begin{center}
            \vspace*{1.5in}
              \scalebox{1.25}{  
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                  \hline
                   Fruit & Color \\
                  \hline
                  \hline                                    
                  Apple & red \\
                  \hline
                  \hline                            
                  Banana & Yellow \\
                  \hline
                \end{tabular}   
              }         
          \end{center}
            \caption{Demo Table 2}
            \vspace*{50pt}
        \end{table}

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\cleardoublepage        

\end{document}
```

Here's the `LoF` result post customization:

[image: Customized look for List of Figures]

And if we comment-out the following lines from our code's preamble:

```
 %% Adding horizontal space between LoF numbers and entry text
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{1in}                         %% Exaggerated width!
\renewcommand{\cftsubfignumwidth}{1in}                      %% Exaggerated width!

%% Indentation for LoF entry numbers
\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\cftsubfigindent}{2.25em}

%% Vertical skips for LoF entries
\renewcommand{\cftbeforefigskip}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubfigskip}{8pt}

%% Customisation of subfig numbers in the LoF entries
\renewcommand{\cftsubfigpresnum}{[\hspace*{0.5mm}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubfigaftersnum}{{}.\hspace*{0.5mm}]}

%% Figure LoF entries in bold
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftfigdotsep}}

%% To switch-off page numbers of subfigure LoF entries
\cftpagenumbersoff{subfigure}
```

Then the `LoF` defaults to:

[image: Default look for List of Figures]

Here, particularly note the change in horizontal spacing between the image number and text, which is governed in this code by `\cftfignumwidth` (figures) & `\cftsubfignumwidth` (subfigures). Rest of the customization is of course optional and dependent on user preference. Hope this helps!

Comment: To the entity who down-voted this answer ... please at least have the decency to explain your down-vote via comments. Simply voting an existing answer without any alternative solution or explanation is easy; whereas posting a solution of your own isn't! Please be mindful of that.